# Passing current server name from SQL Server Agent job to PowerShell

Tags: sql-server-agent, powershell

I have a SQL Server Agent job that calls a PowerShell script in one step. And I want to pass the SQL server name and the current job-id to my script.

With the job-id I have no problems. But with the server name...

My PowerShell call looks like this:

```
.\StopServices.ps1 -ServerName $(ESCAPE_DQUOTE(A-SVR)) -JobId $(ESCAPE_DQUOTE(JOBID))
```

The job-id works perfect, but the server name is empty.

How can I pass the server name to my PowerShell script?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Replace `A-SVR` with `SRVR`.

`A-SVR` is for alerts.

`SRVR` will contain server name and instance name.

[Refer to document on MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175575.aspx).

Comment: Many thanks! That was the mistake... "D'oh!" :)